# create a new variable in r using for loop based on the condition of an existing variable

Tags: r, loops

Suppose the data frame is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,7,8,15,24,100,9,19,128))
```

How do I create a new variable that satisfies the following condition:

```
y = 1 if 1<=x<=7
y = 2 if 8<=x<=14
y = 3 if 15<=x<=21
...
y = k if 1+7*(k-1)<= x<= 7+7*(k-1)
```

so that I can have the new data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(1,1,2,3,4,15, 2,3, 19))
```

I am wondering if a for loop can be applied in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via simple algebra, you can do:

```
df$y <- floor((df$x+6)/7)
df
#     x  y
# 1   1  1
# 2   7  1
# 3   8  2
# 4  15  3
# 5  24  4
# 6 100 15
# 7   9  2
# 8  19  3
# 9 128 19
```

In R you will often find it easier (less typing and less thinking) to use vectorized operators than for loops for simple computations like this. In this case we performed calls to `+`, `/`, and `floor` over a whole vector instead of looping and using them on each element.